# Why is my Express server returning a 404 when submitting the form and not displaying console.log messages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

Trying to create multi-user sessions (think Google Docs) but for some reason my server file doesn't do anything, I've made sure my fetch function is correct yet nothing is changing. Even console.log from the server file commands are not showing. I'm not sure what I am missing here. I'm also using using a random link generator function but I do not think that is relevant as the link generates properly, nevertheless I will include it in my code.

Server.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const fs = require('fs');


const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());



app.post('/api/session', (req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const sessionLink = req.body.sessionLink;
  
    // Create a data object to store the name and session link
    const data = {
      name,
      sessionLink,
    };
  
    // Write the data to a file
    fs.writeFile('data.json', JSON.stringify(data), (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send('Error writing to file');
      } else {
        res.send('Success');
      }
    });
  });
  
  app.listen(3000, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Error starting server:', error);
    } else {
      console.log('Server is listening on port 3000');
    }
  });
```

mainpage.js

```js
 const generateSessionLink = () => {
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    let result = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
    }
    return 'https://mywebsite.io/session/' + result;
  };

 
  const handleNameChange = (event) => {
    setName(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSessionLinkChange = (event) => {
    setSessionLink(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleEnterSession = () => {
    if (name.trim() === '') {
      alert('Please enter your name or nickname.');
      return;
    }
    
  
    if (sessionLink.trim() === '') {
      alert('Please enter a session link or join an existing one.');
      return;
    }
  
    // Make a POST request to the session endpoint
    fetch('/api/session', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name,
        sessionLink
      })
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        // Store the name and session link in local storage
        localStorage.setItem('name', name);
        localStorage.setItem('sessionLink', sessionLink);
  
        // Redirect to the app page
        window.location.href = "/app";
      } else {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      alert('An error occurred while trying to join the session. Please try again later.');
    });
  };
```

Comment: Did you try: `http://localhost:3000/api/session`

Comment: @bill.gates yup, nothing changed.

Comment: I suggest hooking up [morgan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan) `app.use(require('morgan')('combined'))` (or any other logger) and it will log which url was requested and how it responded and you can see if the URL makes sense or has a typo or the wrong HTTP method (POST vs GET) or whatever.  If there's no action whatsoever on the server side then you've likely got the wrong host and port in your URL on the browser side as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code and the only thing you are doing wrong is the fetch URL, because the Node server is not running on the same port/host as your page. If this still doesn't solve your issue then you have to check the browser console, there's probably more info there.

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/session', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name,
        sessionLink
      })
    })
```

Comment: It says that i'm not allowed to run the front-end portion on the same port since the backend portion is running there as well.